# youtube-dl change output path only for converted videos (--recode-video)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, youtube-dl

I want to download a video with `bestvideo+bestaudio` quality and save the converted video to a different location.

for example command below

```
youtube-dl -f bestvideo+bestaudio -k 1G4isv_Fylg
```

produces this:
[image: output]

but I want something like this:
[image: required output]

Can I change the location for **ffmpeg** output?

Comment: this line works for me. What is the error? or what do you need fixed? Please update your question with examples on what is wrong, log output or STDOUT so we can see the actual problem? More details will be very helpful.

Comment: this command 
`youtube-dl -f bestvideo+bestaudio -k 1G4isv_Fylg` 
results in this https://i.imgur.com/79RAZDC.png

But I want something like this:
https://i.imgur.com/Of17upj.png

**That is I want ffmpeg converted video in different  location**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the documentation [here](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md). The solution was to use **--exec** flag

```
youtube-dl -f bestvideo+bestaudio -k --exec 'mv {} ./output/{}'  1G4isv_Fylg
```

I found that command passed as an argument to **--exec** runs only after file conversion and only affects the final output file, that is, in this case, is the converted file.

Answer (score 0):

1)

If you need `youtube-dl` to save your output to a specific folder, you can use:

```
youtube-dl -f bestvideo+bestaudio --recode-video mkv -k https://www.youtube.com/playlist\?list\=PLsJOg0Nj12expAc_emQZb6O1sMzT833yP
 -o 'output/%(title)s.%(ext)s'
```

This will save all of the output in this folder. As you are using `-k` other files will be saved there as well.

2)

Another option is that you manually move the .mvk files to a separate folder, on youtube-dl finishes..

something like:

```
youtube-dl -f bestvideo+bestaudio --recode-video mkv -k https://www.youtube.com/playlist\?list\=PLsJOg0Nj12expAc_emQZb6O1sMzT833yP
mkdir -p output
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.mkv" -exec mv {} output/ \;
```

Comment: Yes, exactly I also thought about this, but say I don't want to **recode** the video then video formats like **webm** can cause some trouble.
https://i.imgur.com/KBJSoeZ.png

Comment: then remove `--recode-video mkv` from the line. If this answer helped you resolve your issue, please mark it as Accepted Answer.